# How to pass two or more selection argument in "query" method

Tags: android

I am using query method, but I don't no how to pass more than one selection argument in query method.

My query method should return result as same as this sql statement :

```
SELECT _id FROM CONATCT_TAGS WHERE TAG1='tagname' OR
                                   TAG2='tagname' OR 
                                   TAG3='tagname' OR 
                                   TAG4='tagname' OR
                                   TAG5='tagname';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like that..

```
SQLiteDatabase db = YourDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String TABLE = "CONTACT_TAGS";
String[] FIELDS = { "_id" };
String WHERE =  "TAG1='tagname' OR TAG2='tagname' OR TAG3='tagname' OR TAG4='tagname' OR TAG5='tagname' ";
// Execute
cursor = db.query(TABLE, FIELDS, WHERE, null, null, null, null);
```

If you read the documentation of the [Cursor.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method you find the definition for `selection` as follows:

> selection: A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an
>   SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will
>   return all rows for the given table.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to use the built-in optimization in the Android SQLite connection you could do something like this instead:

```
String table = "CONTACT_TAGS";
String[] columns = {"_id"};
String where = "TAG1=? OR TAG2=? OR TAG3=? OR TAG4=? OR TAG5=?";
String[] args = {"tagname", "tagname", "tagname", "tagname", "tagname"};

SQLiteDatabase db = myDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, where, args, null, null, null);
```

The difference from @raultum's solution is that you let the database connector decide how to interpret the submitted data. This is extra interesting from a security perspective.

Comment: You want to do with this solution as is used the `args` argument properly to use it to avoid SQL injections

Comment: Has anyone ever gotten this to work?  When I try it leaves the '?' in for all fields instead of subbing in my args.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like that

```
  String strSelection = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE +
  " = " + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE+ 
  " OR " +  android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE +
  " = " + CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this code i getting all documents files using media store, using single query with multiple arguments.

```
 String pdf = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    String doc = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("doc");
    String docx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("docx");
    String xls = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("xls");
    String xlsx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("xlsx");
    String ppt = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("ppt");
    String pptx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pptx");
    String txt = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("txt");
    String rtx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("rtx");
    String rtf = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("rtf");
    String html = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("html");

    //Table
    Uri table = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    //Column
    String[] column = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
    //Where
    String where = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?"
            +" OR " +MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    //args
    String[] args = new String[]{pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,txt,rtx,rtf,html};

    Cursor fileCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(table, column, where, args, null);

    while (fileCursor.moveToNext()) {

    //your code 


    }
```