# Get all unique values from SQLite column as string array

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

I try to get all unique values from database coulmn using SELECT DISTINCT sql command.
But i get exception when my activity is loading, i have this error code in logcat:

```
05-05 09:08:32.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM exerciseTable WHERE SELECT DISTINCTexercise_typefromexerciseTable
```

I think that i have not wrote the command correctly, here is my code:

```
public String[] getAllExercies() {
        String selecet = "SELECT DISTINCT" + COLUMN_EXERCISE + "from" + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selecet, null, null, null, null);
        int dayExercise = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXERCISE);

        String[] list = new String[c.getCount()-1];
        int j = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            list[j] = c.getString(dayExercise);
            j++;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should first checkout these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507332/1306419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758320/1306419) in order to see the working of .query() function.
Please note that while using `ourDatabase.query()` function, the parameters are as follows:

```
String Table Name: The name of the table to run the query against
String [ ] columns: The projection of the query, i.e., the columns to retrieve
String WHERE clause: where clause, if none then pass null
String [ ] selection args: The parameters of the WHERE clause
String Group by: A string specifying group by clause
String Having: A string specifying HAVING clause
String Order By by: A string Order By by clause
```

So your third variable should be a **WHERE** clause, something like:

```
String[] args = { "first string" };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("TABLE_NAME", null, "exercise_type=?", args, null, null, null);
```

Since you don't need a WHERE clause, for your purposes you might want to use rawQuery() method instead.

```
String selecet = "SELECT DISTINCT " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
ourDatabase.rawQuery(selecet, null);
```

**Update**
Try the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879436/1306419). Do something like this:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, "exerciseTable", new String[] {"exercise_type"}, null, null, "exercise_type", null, null, null);
int dayExercise = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXERCISE);
//... continue with your further code
```

Hope this helps else please comment.

Comment: Thank you!
My loop to convert the Cursor to string array will work good with rawQuery method?

Comment: Yes. It should. The Cursor concept is the same but just the way of querying is just different for both. If you just have a simple Sqllite query, you can directly use rawQuery() method to run it.

Comment: *You need not change anything in the loop.

Comment: I tried it, and i still got force close.
here is the cat log:' 05-05 10:17:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM exerciseTable WHERE SELECT DISTINCT exercise_typefrom exerciseTable

Comment: You can see from the error that the query you are making is wrong: `SELECT * FROM exerciseTable WHERE SELECT DISTINCT exercise_typefrom exerciseTable`. It should be something like: `SELECT DISTINCT exercise_type from exerciseTable`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man, its finally works :)
that line is working:
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, "exerciseTable", new String[] {"exercise_type"}, null, null, "exercise_type", null, null, null);

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**
you have not maintained the `space` between the words.

**Explaination:**

suppose, `String COLUMN_EXERCISE = "exercise";`

and `String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_workout";`

then
`String selecet = "SELECT DISTINCT" + COLUMN_EXERCISE + "from" + TABLE_NAME;`

simply means,`SELECT DISTINCTexercisefromtbl_workout`

**Solution:**

`String selecet = "SELECT DISTINCT " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + " from " + TABLE_NAME;`

**Edit:**

Kindly use following syntax to fire rawQuery

`Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selecet,null);`

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: I tried it.
I still got force close.
here is the cat log:'

05-05 10:17:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM exerciseTable WHERE SELECT DISTINCT exercise_typefrom exerciseTable

Answer (score 0):

You miss all the spaces in your query, you should replace with this:

```
String selecet = "SELECT DISTINCT " + COLUMN_EXERCISE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: i knew it was there...
Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: I still got force close.
here is the cat log:'

05-05 10:17:43.507: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM exerciseTable WHERE SELECT DISTINCT exercise_typefrom exerciseTable