# How to construct sql query for mutiple where values

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to build a query.

Below is the table of my DB:

```
ID          Name
20          ABC1
30          ABC2
40          ABC3
60          ABC4
70          ABC5
80          ABC6
```

I need to get the records for the ID's 30 , 40 , 70.

I have written a query as below , but its giving me error.

```
String query =  "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID = '30','40','70' "
```

The above query I am passing to below method:

```
db.rawQuery(query ,null);
```

but its throwing below error:

```
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(19091): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error, db=xxx
```

Please let me know what can be do to resolve the issue.

Comment: String query =  "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID IN ('30','40','70') "

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular SQL syntax for that:

```
String query =  "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID = '30' OR ID = '40' OR ID = '70' "
```

By the way, you can use in convenient android way:

[Exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757263/how-to-pass-two-or-more-selection-argument-in-query-method)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write instead `WHERE ID IN ('30', '40', '70')`

Also I strongly suggest you using db.query instead of db.rawQuery to avoid the possible sql injection attack or general string escaping mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID in ('30','40','70')"
```